# Lifetime of static (class) variables

Tags: java, android, static

for quite some time i was blissfully of the opinion that static [instance] variables exist as long as the app runs. however, to my dismay, and much alarm, i feel that it's not true.

for mere testing, i created a static list of strings, and in my main `activity` class overrode the `onDestroy` method to print a message to verify that the app exited. in the `onCreate` method i simply added a new `string`, and printed the contents of the list. what i've found is that the size of the list keeps on increasing, and all the string values added previously are still present.

i've read in places [even here on SO] that the instance variables exist as long as the app does, but i fear it's not really so.

to be more precise, i came to be aware of this problem while using the Facebook SDK for Android. i've seen that the `AuthListener` instances within the list of listeners in the `SessionEvents` class just keeps on increasing over time. Hence, whenever the app is launched and the user logs in using FB, the listener methods get triggered as many times as there are instances present in the `SessionEvents` class.

Has someone observed this before, and is there some cardinal mistake i'm committing in understanding how android works?

what gives?

thanks for reading!

[**UPDATE**]
I stand corrected by `BalusC` and `rdineiu`. I really didn't mean to create a confusion here about instance and class variables. Alas, in my haste to post my question i've committed a mistake i didn't wish to. I am very well aware of the difference between `static` and `instance` variables. I just intended to write `class` variables, and can't quite figure out what came over to refer to static variables as `instance` variables.

However, my question still stands. 
**@MisterSquonk** - no, i'm not confusing here about when my `Activity` ends and when the app gets destroyed. Here's what I tried on a sample - I've got only ONE `Activity` which serves as the `Main`. When I press the back button from this `Activity`, I'm assuming the `Activity` gets removed from the stack **and** the app also gets destroyed. I've launched the Task Manager to verify that my app is no longer running.

Comment: static variables != instance variables

Comment: Not directly related to your question but in reference to something you said..."in my main activity class overrode the onDestroy method to print a message to verify that the app exited" - Don't confuse Activity with Application. Killing an Activity does NOT necessarily kill the Application ("the app").

Comment: @MisterSquonk - no i'm not making any such confusion. in my particular app, i'm quite certain that the killing of the `activity` also means that the app is no longer running. i verified it using the task manager, and have updated the post to mention the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so - i had posted the same question [unfortunately making the same mistake of terming `static` variables as `instance` variables] on the Android Developer Google group.

I received some really good responses, especially from **Kostya**. My interactions on that group helped me to grasp the underlying "rules" of the Android platform.

Hope the [message thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_frm/thread/387555e3011b38cb/aad8af2b2843c543?lnk=gst&q=anirvan.majumdar#aad8af2b2843c543) helps you as well.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to not make the distinction between static and instance variables. Static variables are defined on the class itself. Instance variables are present only in class instances.

Example:

```
class Test {
    public static int a;
}
```

The variable `a` is defined on the *class itself*, not on instances of the class. Each instance will access the *same* variable. If one instance sets the value of `a` to `5`, every other instance will see the value as `5`. The variable will not vanish once the instance vanishes, because it is in no way tied to any instance (it's a *class variable*). It will continue to be there until the end of time (or until the application exits, whichever comes first).

On the other hand, the following example uses an instance variable:

```
class Test {
    public int a;
}
```

This variable will be accessible only from *instances* of the class. Each instance will have a different copy of the variable. Once the instance gets destroyed, the variable goes with it.

---

To illustrate:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test {
  // instanceVar will be initialized whenever a new Test object is created
  private List<Integer> instanceVar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  // staticVar will be initialized right now
  private static List<Integer> staticVar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public void updateInstanceVar() {
    instanceVar.add(1);
    instanceVar.add(2);
  }

  public void updateStaticVar() {
    staticVar.add(1);
    staticVar.add(2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test1 = new Test();
    test1.updateInstanceVar(); // test1.instanceVar = [1, 2]
    test1.updateStaticVar();   // Test.staticVar    = [1, 2]

    Test test2 = new Test();
    test2.updateInstanceVar(); // test2.instanceVar = [1, 2]
    test2.updateStaticVar();   // Test.staticVar    = [1, 2, 1, 2]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, and yes - you're absolutely correct. however, as the update to my post suggests, i hope my question's intent doesn't get lost because of the silly mistake i've committed.

Answer (score 0):

The instance variables are destroyed when app does but some gui widgets by default save their state and then restore it in onCreate method.